# Removing a spare HDD from Windows XP causes User Profile to reset

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, user-profiles, safely-remove-hardware

I have 5 internal HDD's installed;

1. HDD 1 IDE partitioned into C (OS) [Pri], I [Logic]
2. HDD 2 IDE partitioned into F (Programs) Pri, G (Games) [Logic]
3. HDD 3 SATA partition H (Empty) [Pri]
4. HDD 4 SATA partition J (Backup) [Pri]
5. HDD 5 SATA partition V (Video) [Pri]

I am running Windows XP SP3 - it's an older computer I use when needed - and having an issue that is baffling me.

I want to remove the SATA HDD 3 (H) to use it in another computer for installing Windows 7 OS. I have removed all data and reformatted the drive, leaving an active partition on it (so I can install the OS on the other computer). However, after I turn off the WinXP computer and remove the HDD, upon restarting my user profile is reset. Upon attempting a System Restore, I am informed that since the "H:" drive is missing, it will not be able to reset all preferences. I tried anyway, and it didn't restore my settings. Any ideas?

I use the Windows XP machine as workhorse for when I have computer issues on other machines, or between builds/rebuilds/upgrades. I'm no expert, more of a dabbler, but I can figure out most problems with a little research, and lots of patience.
I appreciate any assistance, suggestions, or answers provided. Please be as verbose and descriptive as possible.
Thanks.

Comment: search the registry for `ProfileImagePath` and check for anything pointing to `h:` and/or an environment variable delimited with `%` (e.g. %systemroot%). If you see any environment variables, check their value by running a cmd prompt and typing e.g. `echo %systemroot%`. Also: have you made any mount points or junctions? Moved the default location of any libraries such as mydocuments?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try tonight.
I have migrated the MyDocuments folder to the F: drive; I use it to run most programs that don't require being on the OS (Same as with G:, I run most of my Games from). I'm starting to wonder if I should move those partitions onto the same HDD as the OS though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with exactly what "mount points or junctions" are. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, after I turn off the WinXP computer and remove the HDD, upon
>   restarting my user profile is reset. Upon attempting a System Restore,
>   I am informed that since the "H:" drive is missing, it will not be
>   able to reset all preferences. I tried anyway, and it didn't restore
>   my settings. Any ideas?

The simple solution is to mark one of the other partitions as H if the drive contains NO DATA then Windows won't know the difference. Do this BEFORE you remove the drive.

Comment: Thanks, I considered doing that. Then, after having removed the HDD and rebooting - if that works - I can simply delete the new H: partition?

Comment: @ShawnJones - There is a reason that Windows is using the `H` parition you need to figure out the reason.  My guess at some point you see your profile to work off the `H` drive and since have changed that.  You will need to find the setting and/or registery key that contains `H` as the storage location and change it to any drive letter you want.  I just provided a simple solution to the problem.